# How to make a gradient for text from color to color?

Tags: html, css

How to make a gradient for text from color to color?

```css
 .gradient {
     background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, green 100%);
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
     font-size: 300%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="gradient">COUNTRY</div>
```

Comment: display:table (or dispaly:inline-block) to the div

Comment: Add div too `display:inline `.because Div having width:100%; so text is to small.

Comment: It makes the width of text has the width of div :)

Comment: Thanks, I use display:inline and it works how need.

Comment: why are you accepting an answer that doesn't provide the solution that seems to work for you? this doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make some changes to your CSS.

```css
          .gradient {
font-size: 72px;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 10%, green 50%);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue 10%, green 50%);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">COUNTRY</div>
```

You can try this code of CSS.

Comment: It doesn't work if open it in a full window.

Comment: Div having width:100% to add `display:inline` .

Comment: Thanks, I use display:inline and it works how need.

Answer (score 1):

Change your "green" color percentage like:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, green 10%)
```